# Safe to have specific RESTful API endpoint without CSRF tokens?

Tags: xss, csrf, django

I have a RESTful API. There are two ways to authenticate to it: a user/password-centric model, and OAuth2.

Although user/password-authenticated users can make requests to this specific API endpoint, they are rejected in the Django view code. Only clients that have authenticated via OAuth2 and have permissions to access this resource may make changes or view data.

Other server software that POSTs to this endpoint - which I don't have any control over - don't support CSRF tokens.

Are there any security risks in exposing end points like this? I figure that there aren't, since a web user cannot do anything more than trigger code that will reject them. Do I need any additional precautions?

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by the view code is rejecting them? Unless I'm misunderstanding, the code in the view wouldnt reject them because its on the client side and a csrf vulnerability would post directly to the server, or maybe im misunderstanding.

Comment: Sorry, "views" is what Django calls the code that executes when a request is made